# Radio will not work

Tags: audio

I have the radio code to unlock my radio however when I enter it it will not work. It comes up with an error code. So frustrated what should I do?

Comment: Please specify the make, model and year as the entry method varies.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! We feel your pain! However, we can't help you without knowing the information as Solar Mike stated. Please help us to help you! :o) Also include what you're doing to input the code ... that'll let us know if you're doing something wrong and how we can assist.